# Two operators multiplication in the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff Lemma

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

When I was learning the transformation from the Schrodinger picture to the interaction picture in quantum mechanics, I have to use the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorf Lemma,
\begin{align}
e^ABe^{-A}=B+[A,B]+\frac{1}{2!}[A,[A,B]]+\ldots.
\end{align}
I was wondering what if there are two operators needed to be transformed, namely
\begin{align}
e^ABCe^{-A}=BC+[A,BC]+\frac{1}{2!}[A,[A,BC]]+\ldots.
\end{align}
I expand each term in $BC$ as
\begin{align}
e^ABCe^{-A}=BC+[A,B]C+B[A,C]+\frac{1}{2!}\left\{[A,[A,B]]C+B[A,[A,C]]+2[A,B][A,C]\right\}+\ldots.
\end{align}
Now I use the shorthand notation that
\begin{align}
[A,X]=[X]^1,\ \ [A,[A,X]]=[X]^2,\ \ [A,[A,[A,X]]]=[X]^3,\ldots,
\end{align}
for $X$ is operator $B$ and $C$. Then, it shows
\begin{align}
e^ABCe^{-A}=&BC+[B]^1C+B[C]^1+\frac{1}{2!}([B]^2C+2[B]^1[C]^1+B[C]^2)\\
&+\frac{1}{3!}([B]^3C+3[B]^2[C]^1+3[B]^1[C]^2+B[C]^3)\\
&+\frac{1}{4!}([B]^4C+4[B]^3[C]^1+6[B]^2[C]^2+4[B]^1[C]^3+B[C]^4)+\ldots.
\end{align}
I notice that the coefficients of these terms actually follow **the rows of the Pascal's triangle**. For practical purposes, I want to find an expression of this expansion (I primarily assume that $[B,C]=0$ $[A,B]\neq0$ and $[A,C]\neq0$).

Is this already investigated in mathematics? If it has been, could you share that with me?

Thank you!

Comment: One thing to note here is that we are moving away from Lie algebras when we talk about $BC$ since the only defined product on a Lie algebra is the bracket. Of course if you instead use the bracket you get that $\mathrm{Ad} e^A$ is an automorphism so $\mathrm{Ad} e^A([B,C]) =[\mathrm{Ad} e^A(B),\mathrm{Ad} e^A(C)]$.

Comment: We can assume that we are expanding to consider some associative matrix algebra containing the Lie algebra we can make sense of $BC$. But then unless you already know the repeated action of A on B and C separately already is you formula any easier than $BC + [BC]^1 + \frac{1}{2}[BC]^2 +\cdots$?

Comment: @Callum Thank you for your comment. Indeed, I did not focus on the Lie algebras of the expansion of $BC$. My original purpose is to simplify the calculation of $e^A BC e^{-A}$ and try to separate them into an expression regarding $B$ and an expression regarding $C$. But I failed to do it since the number of terms is increasing, in which the coefficients satisfy the binomial theorem. Thus, I was asking whether this had been studied before.

Comment: Not sure this is helpful but $e^ABCe^{-A}=e^ABe^{-A}e^{A}Ce^{-A}$ so you can refactor to a product of the bch expansion of $e^ABe^{-A}$ and $e^ACe^{-A}$.

Comment: @user619894 Hi, is there any source of $e^A BC e^{-A}=e^A B e^{-A}e^A C e^{-A}$? It looks weird to me.

Comment: Shouldn't look weird, it is a matrix times its inverse: $I=e^{-A}e^{A}$

Comment: @user619894 Ohh, I didn't imagine that I could do it in this way. Thank you so much. Your answer is really helpful!  ;)